# How to hide specific dots and labels onmouseover in highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

In this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/stock/demo/compare/) placed on highcharts.com I'd like to hide dots when mouse is over on current `yAxis` and also erase `labels` from `tooltip`, but no erase the graphs.

Below trivial image with red lines and crosses to hide:
[image: Image with things to hide]

Comment: From this image - how would it know to hide MSFT and APPL? What are the rules for hiding? Can the hidden items change depending on location of mouse pointer?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by [`tooltip.shared`](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#tooltip.shared) which defaults to `true`. From the documentation (emphasis mine):

> When the tooltip is shared, the **entire plot area will capture mouse movement**.

Since you only want to capture mouse movement over individual series, we can just set the value to be `false` and that should resolve the matter. In your example:

```
// ... other options
tooltip: {
    pointFormat: '<span style="color:{series.color}">{series.name}</span>: <b>{point.y}</b> ({point.change}%)<br/>',
    valueDecimals: 2,
    shared: false
}
```